# Hiding div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `operations-box` is my div element in `html` i want to have hidden when the website is open and display it after click the `Show more` button.

```js
'use strict';
const btnGhost = document.querySelector('.btn-ghost');
const operationsBox = document.querySelector('.operations-box');
const init = function () {
    operationsBox.classList.add('hidden');
}

init();

btnGhost.addEventListener('click', function () {
    operationsBox.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="main-text-box">
    <h1 class="main-welcoming-text"><span style="color: #fff">Cars menagement</span><br>Operate your cars collection</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">About me</a>
    <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<div class="operations-box"></div>
</header>
```

[image]

The result after opening website is like that: (this white box is my operations-box which should be hidden). Can anybody explain what is wrong with my code and what can i change to let it works?

Comment: Give it the class by default?

Comment: It's likely the styles are being overridden by something else with higher specificity. That or the JS is failing to give the div the class

Comment: You have most likely put the code in the HEAD, where it runs before the HTML have been read and created in the DOM, hence the code can't find the element. The console should have given an error. To solve this, put the script last or call `init()` through `window.addEventListener('load', init())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `init()` function is only adding this class to element and is always performed whenever script is loaded then you don't need it.
Simply add class `hidden` to `operations-box` like in example below.

```js
'use strict';
const btnGhost = document.querySelector('.btn-ghost');
const operationsBox = document.querySelector('.operations-box');

btnGhost.addEventListener('click', function () {
    operationsBox.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="main-text-box">
    <h1 class="main-welcoming-text"><span style="color: #fff">Cars menagement</span><br>Operate your cars collection</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">About me</a>
    <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show more</a>
</div>
<div class="operations-box hidden"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this
Give it an id in html like this

```
<div class="operations-box" id="operations"></div>
```

In CSS do this

```
.operations-box:{
   display:none
}
```

in JS do this:

```
myDiv = document.getElementById('operations')
```

create a functoin to change display like this:

```
function showDiv(){
myDiv.display = 'inherit'
}
```

and lastly call this function `showDiv()` on click event of button you want to imply this functionality like his.

```
<button onclick='showDiv()'>Click Me!</button>
```